# Sentry: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ceCurrentVideo.currentTime')

Tags: javascript, sentry

Getting the below error in our Sentry logs.

> TypeError i(@sentry/browser/esm/helpers)
>
> **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ceCurrentVideo.currentTime')**

Definitely a third party something, but my search for what this could be has turned up nothing, so reaching out if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Does this help in any way? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/3040#issuecomment-913549441

Comment: Try searching for `ceCurrentVideo`object within all directories including `node_modules` seperately.

Comment: Unfortunately the sentry issue was not directly helpful, but it certainly sounds like a webkit problem.

I did check node_modules in my search.. and now the only meaningful google result on this error is this post lol..

Answer (score 2):

Received the exact same error in Sentry. I'm getting it from a user on Mobile Safari on iPhone where the third-party stuff is more limited.

Comment: Have about 15+ users so far, Mobile Safari iOS 15.4, 15.4.1, and Mac OS 10.15.6.

Comment: Also getting this on Mobile Safari

Comment: It does not answer the enquirer's question. You'd better comment instead as per descriptions with the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting this error on New Relic and searching doesn't come up with much. Hoping someone can provide some information on this

Comment: It does not answer the enquirer's question. You'd better comment instead as per descriptions with the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).